# Incorrect railroad diagram for ALTER TABLE with multiple out-of-line constraints?

Tags: sql, oracle, alter-table

Currently using 18c but this apparent inconsistency is present in earlier versions (certainly back to 11g).

In this particular case, I am adding multiple out-of-line constraints to an existing table.

All railroad diagrams are found here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html

This is the railroad diagram for `ALTER TABLE`:

[image]

Then, this is the railroad diagram for `constraint_clauses`:

[image]

Finally, this is the railroad diagram for `out_of_line_constraint`:

[image]

There are no `(` and `)` or a `,` in the railroad diagram. But the SQL query must have them.

Here is the code that works:

```
Create table a ( x number );

Alter table a add (
  constraint x1 check ( x > 0 ),
  constraint x2 check ( x < 10)
);
```

Where is my mistake in reading and interpreting the railroad diagram? Is there something else I must know?

Comment: I think the mistake is in the Oracle documentation and not in your understanding of it. I write a separate `ALTER TABLE` statement for each constraint. Maybe most people do the same and that's why no-one is complaining. Or maybe people figure out how to add the missing parts, as you did and hence don't complain. I searched for how to report mistakes in the documentation to Oracle but couldn't find it. Maybe you could try [Ask TOM](https://asktom.oracle.com)

Comment: @Abra Not really worth reporting it I suppose. I guess the underlying issue is that in the railroad diagram you'd have to have separate paths for the single constraint and multiple constraint cases: no parens when you have a single constraint, parens and comma when you have multiple. I am still wondering why I didn't manage to find any mentions of this obious inconsistency anywhere online.

Comment: @Abra I also anticipated an answer along the lines of "this is how you have to group things always anyway in the context of DDLs" or something of that sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *need* parentheses or commas.  This works:

```
alter table a 
  add constraint x1 check (x > 0)
  add constraint x2 check (x < 10);
```

But it's a documentation bug either way, as the railroad diagram does not indicate that the "constraint_clauses" reference is repeatable.

Comment: I will have to try this out on Monday. The railroad diagram **does indicate** that the `out_of_line_constraint` is repeatable, see my question. So your example above, if it works, is _exactly_ what the railroad diagram says.

Comment: Sorry, spoke too soon. So the `ADD` is not inside the loop, so this is still not as documented.

Comment: So, your code works, and it is not in the railroad diagram, just like my code that also works ;-) I am now left wondering what to do with this information. Either way, thank you for taking the time.

Comment: As far as what to do, you could open a service request to log the documentation bugs (there are several here).  In the meantime, if you want to be totally safe, I guess write one constraint per `ALTER` statement, in accordance with the railroad diagrams.  Theoretically, Oracle could drop support of any undocumented syntax.

Comment: I am not sure about writing one constraint per `ALTER` statement, sometimes it is kinda important that all constraints are added in a single transaction.

Answer (score 1):

[Create table doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402) include parentheses:

[image]

For one constraint statement, parentheses is optional, for example:

```
Alter table a add constraint x1 check ( x > 0 )
```

I don't see parentheses for constraint in doc, which seems missing as you found.

Here's [full oracle syntax document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/toc.htm)

Comment: What is the relationship between CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE? I have learned the hard way that I can't make assumptions about anything.... I also couldn't find anyone else complaining about this, so I still suspect I am not reading the railroad diagram correctly.

Comment: @user9213 *After creating a table, you can define additional columns, partitions, and integrity constraints with the ADD clause of the ALTER TABLE statement*

Comment: @user9213 I think there is a missing parentheses reference for adding constraint using alter table